# Convert csv file into a javascript object

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a csv file which contains a list of airports and its coordinates.

```
JFK, 40.63980103, -73.77890015
LAX, 33.94250107, -118.4079971
SEA, 47.44900131, -122.3089981
```

How would I parse the content into a Javascript object like this?

```
{ 
  JFK: { lat: 40.63980103, lng: -73.77890015 },
  LAX: { lat: 33.94250107, lng: -118.4079971 },
  SEA: { lat: 47.44900131, lng: -122.3089981 }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Convert+csv+file+into+a+javascript+object

Comment: split it on new lines, loop over split on commas, change it to an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You split on new lines, split on commas, and use reduce to make the objects.

```js
var csv = `JFK, 40.63980103, -73.77890015
LAX, 33.94250107, -118.4079971
SEA, 47.44900131, -122.3089981`;

// split on lines
const data = csv.split(/\n/).reduce((obj, line) => {
  // split on commas
  var parts = line.split(/,/);
  obj[parts[0].trim()] = {
    lat: +parts[1],
    lng: +parts[2],
  };
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Watch out in case the CSV has commas, newlines and quotes in a field, such as: `"Newton, ""Jimmy"" James"`, which results in field: `Newton, "Jimmy" James`. In that case you need a proper CSV parser such as https://github.com/peterthoeny/parse-csv-js

Comment: @PeterThoeny When it is simple, you do not need a parser.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone could have some CodeGolf fun with this one but here's a simple solution. This is very coupled to the data set so I'd suggest considering whether you'll have different shaped csv's (as in different headers, row+columns, etc) before committing to this solution.

```
const data = `JFK, 40.63980103, -73.77890015
LAX, 33.94250107, -118.4079971
SEA, 47.44900131, -122.3089981`

const splitByLines = data.split(/\n/)
const splitByCommas = splitByLines.map(arr => arr.split(','))

const output = {}
splitByCommas.map(([loc, lat, lon ]) => {
  output[loc] = { lat, lon }
})

console.log(output)
```